# My animation won't start

Tags: objective-c, animation, uikit

I've done this code to start animation when i click a button, when I click the button is should change what the button says and start the animation, but it only changes what the button says ? Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
@synthesize SwishImage;
@synthesize SwishButton;

- (IBAction) Swish {
if (SwishImage.isAnimating) {
    [SwishImage stopAnimating];
    [SwishButton setTitle:@"Swish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [SwishImage startAnimating];
    [SwishButton setTitle:@"Searching" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
- (void)viewdidload
{

NSArray * SwishArray;
SwishArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange_dot.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                   nil];
    SwishImage.animationImages=SwishArray;
    SwishImage.animationDuration = 1;
    SwishImage.animationRepeatCount = 0;


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copied this into an empty Xcode project and linked everything correctly in Interface Builder the image view started animating. I assume something isn't correctly linked in Interface Builder.

That being said, your code is a bit awkward from a standards perspective. Variable names should begin with a lower case letter (and that includes properties). You don't need @synthesize anymore and there is a new shortcut for NSArray. Here is how your classes should look:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *swishImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *swishButton;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *swishArray = @[
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange_dot.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
    ];
    self.swishImage.animationImages=swishArray;
    self.swishImage.animationDuration = 1;
    self.swishImage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
}

- (IBAction)swish:(id)sender {
    if (self.swishImage.isAnimating) {
        [self.swishImage stopAnimating];
        [self.swishButton setTitle:@"Swish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.swishImage startAnimating];
        [self.swishButton setTitle:@"Searching" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

@end
```

Then just select your image view and go to the Connections Inspector. You should see a section titled Referencing Outlets, make sure that swishImage is connected to your view controller.

Comment: thanks very much for the advice, I am new to coding and picking it up in leaps and bounds. I've started sorting out my naming convention. Its sometimes hard to learn by following tutorial's with methods that are outdated now!